# Why do some characters change the overall line height, and how can this be fixed?

Tags: html, css, height

For some reason, when using some characters, the indentation of the line height changes:

```css
div {
 width: auto;
 margin: 8px;
 padding: 8px;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid blue;
}

.box {
 width: 22px;
 height: 22px;
 color: green;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #eee;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div><span class="box">☉</span> foo</div><br>
<div><span class="box">&bull;</span> foo</div>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HusoT.png)

In this picture, you can see that there is a one pixel difference.

I have looked through many CSS properties but could not find any that could initially specify the desired indentation.

Comment: vertical-align: middle; to .box element. It's the line-height, it's the alignment that change

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, it helps to solve my problem too.

Comment: in my previous comment I meant it's NOT the line-height (forget the not)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I understood

Comment: @TemaniAfif perhaps this should be added as an answer?

Comment: I am searching for a related question dealing with the same issue (I remember there is one)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can define the line height manually:

```
.box{
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

Comment: It looks like your solution works, but I can't understand why, for each span element, this value doesn't change in the Inspector and is set to 20px by default?

Answer (score -1):

Please Update your CSS. You can set line-height

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
 width: auto;
 margin: 8px;
 padding: 8px;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 
}
.box {
 width: 22px;
 height: 22px;
 color: green;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #eee;
 border: 1px solid red;
 padding:2px;
 line-height: 24px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div><span class="box">☉</span> foo</div><br>
<div><span class="box">&bull;</span> foo</div><br>
<div><span class="box">&#8226;</span> foo</div><br>
<div><span class="box">&#8364;</span> foo</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, but I can't understand why, for each span element, this value doesn't change in the Inspector and is set to 20px by default?

Comment: It's commonly used to set the distance between lines of text. On block-level elements, it specifies the minimum height of line boxes within the element. But on non-replaced inline elements, it specifies the height that is used to calculate line box height.